# Is it possible for nginx reverse proxy server to compress request body before sending it to backend servers?

Tags: nginx

I was trying to compress request body data before sending it to backend server.
To achieve this, I add my module to the official nginx, my module has a rewrite phase handler,
which I want it to rewrite request body, code shows as below:

```
static ngx_int_t
ngx_http_leap_init(ngx_conf_t *cf)
{
    ngx_http_handler_pt       *h;
    ngx_http_core_main_conf_t *cmcf;

    cmcf = ngx_http_conf_get_module_main_conf(cf, ngx_http_core_module);

    h = ngx_array_push(&cmcf->phases[NGX_HTTP_REWRITE_PHASE].handlers);
    if (h == NULL)
        return NGX_ERROR;
    *h = ngx_http_leap_rewrite_handler;

    return NGX_OK;
}
```

in ngx_http_leap_rewrite_handler method, I have the following line:

```
 rc = ngx_http_read_client_request_body(r, ngx_http_leap_request_body_read);
```

the ngx_http_leap_request_body_read handler is able to compress request body, when posting data using application/x-www-form-urlencoded but not for multipart/form-data.
Because what I really want to do is to compress post files, not post lines,
is there any ideas?